# Virtual Host needs whitespace in DocumentRoot

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, dropbox

How do I use whitespace in mu virtual host file "sites-available" and "sites-enabled"?

I'm currently trying:

```
/var/www/My\ Dropbox/public_html/
```

and it is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding quotation marks ought to do it.

`"/var/www/My Dropbox/public_html/"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean for your DocumentRoot (and not for the domain name)? Put it in quote marks, eg: "/var/www/My Dropbox/public_html".